# CATIA automation in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, catia

I am trying to create a circle using VB.NET. However when I run the code below I get this error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. " I can change the properties of lines and points without any problem, this is only a problem when I try to draw circles. Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

```
Dim inCircle As HybridShapeCircleTritangent

Dim testHB As MECMOD.HybridBody

testHB = part1.FindObjectByName("Test HB")


inCircle = hsf.AddNewCircleTritangent(part1.FindObjectByName("Line.1"), part1.FindObjectByName("Line.2"), part1.FindObjectByName("Line.3"), part1.FindObjectByName("Surf"), -1, 1, -1)
inCircle.DiscriminationIndex = 1
inCircle.BeginOfCircle = 1
inCircle.TangentOrientation1 = -1
inCircle.TangentOrientation2 = 1
inCircle.TangentOrientation3 = -1

inCircle.SetLimitation(1)
testHB.AppendHybridShape(inCircle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create references for the input items of the circle?
Try this:

```
Dim reference2 As Reference
Set reference2 = part1.CreateReferenceFromObject(part1.FindObjectByName("Line.1"))
```

And use the references created

Answer (score 0):

@Matheus Titarelli is correct about needing references to the lines and surfaces. I would not directly call the FindObjectByName in the CreateReferenceFromObject, I would instead set a local variable as the found line (if it exists) first and then create the reference.

@A. Gharbi I do all my Catia development in C# so sadly I do not have a working version of the VB.net that code that I can share with you but I do have a C# version that I use. I did make a rough translation of the VB.net code but have not tested it.

VB.net Code (Untested):

```
'--------------------------------------------------------------
Public Shared Function GetHybridShapeFactory(iPart As MECMOD.Part) As HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeFactory
    If iPart Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim oHSF As HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeFactory = Nothing
    Try
        oHSF = DirectCast(iPart.HybridShapeFactory, HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeFactory)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
    Return oHSF
End Function


'--------------------------------------------------------------
Public Shared Function AddNewCircleTritangent(ByRef iPart As MECMOD.Part, 
                                              ByRef iHB As MECMOD.HybridBody, 
                                              ByRef iLine1 As INFITF.AnyObject, 
                                              ByRef iLine2 As INFITF.AnyObject, 
                                              ByRef iLine3 As INFITF.AnyObject, 
                                              ByRef iSurface As INFITF.AnyObject, 
                                              ByVal iOri1 As Integer, 
                                              ByVal iOri2 As Integer, 
                                              ByVal iOri3 As Integer) As HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeCircleTritangent

    If (iPart Is Nothing) Or (iHB Is Nothing) Or
       (iLine1 Is Nothing) Or (iLine2 Is Nothing) Or
       (iLine3 Is Nothing) Or (iSurface Is Nothing) Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim HSF As HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeFactory = Nothing
    HSF = GetHybridShapeFactory(iPart)
    If HSF Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    ' Get the Reference of the first line
    Dim refLine1 As INFITF.Reference = Nothing
    Try
        refLine1 = iPart.CreateReferenceFromObject(iLine1)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
    If refLine1 Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    ' Get the Reference of the second line
    Dim refLine2 As INFITF.Reference = Nothing
    Try
        refLine2 = iPart.CreateReferenceFromObject(iLine2)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
    If refLine2 Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    ' Get the Reference of the third line
    Dim refLine3 As INFITF.Reference = Nothing
    Try
        refLine3 = iPart.CreateReferenceFromObject(iLine3)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
    If refLine3 Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    ' Get the Reference of the support surface
    Dim refSurf As INFITF.Reference = Nothing
    Try
        refSurf = iPart.CreateReferenceFromObject(iSurface)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
    If refSurf Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    ' Create the object, add it the Geometric set, and update the part.
    Dim HSCTT As HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeCircleTritangent = Nothing
    Try
        HSCTT = DirectCast(HSF.AddNewCircleTritangent(refLine1, refLine2, refLine3, refSurf, iOri1, iOri2, iOri3), HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeCircleTritangent)
        iHB.AppendHybridShape(HSCTT)
        iPart.InWorkObject = HSCTT
        iPart.Update()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

    Return HSCTT
End Function
```

C# code:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public static HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeFactory GetHybridShapeFactory(MECMOD.Part iPart)
{
    if (null == iPart) 
    {
        return null; 
    }

    HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeFactory oHSF = null;
    try
    {
        oHSF = (HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeFactory)iPart.HybridShapeFactory;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { 
        return null;
    }
    return oHSF;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
public static HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeCircleTritangent AddNewCircleTritangent(MECMOD.Part iPart,
                                                                                    MECMOD.HybridBody iHB,
                                                                                    INFITF.AnyObject iLine1,
                                                                                    INFITF.AnyObject iLine2,
                                                                                    INFITF.AnyObject iLine3,
                                                                                    INFITF.AnyObject iSurface,
                                                                                    int iOri1,
                                                                                    int iOri2,
                                                                                    int iOri3)
{
    if ((null == iPart) || (null == iHB) || 
        (null == iLine1) || (null == iLine2) || 
        (null == iLine3) || (null == iSurface))
    {
        return null;
    }

    HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeFactory HSF = null;
    HSF = GetHybridShapeFactory(iPart);
    if (null == HSF)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Get the Reference of the first line
    INFITF.Reference refLine1 = null;
    try
    {
        refLine1 = iPart.CreateReferenceFromObject(iLine1);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (null == refLine1)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Get the Reference of the second line
    INFITF.Reference refLine2 = null;
    try
    {
        refLine2 = iPart.CreateReferenceFromObject(iLine2);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (null == refLine2)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Get the Reference of the third line
    INFITF.Reference refLine3 = null;
    try
    {
        refLine3 = iPart.CreateReferenceFromObject(iLine3);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (null == refLine3)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Get the Reference of the support surface
    INFITF.Reference refSurf = null;
    try
    {
        refSurf = iPart.CreateReferenceFromObject(iSurface);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (null == refSurf)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Create the object, add it the Geometric set, and update the part.
    HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeCircleTritangent HSCTT = null;
    try
    {
        HSCTT = (HybridShapeTypeLib.HybridShapeCircleTritangent)HSF.AddNewCircleTritangent(refLine1, 
                                                                                           refLine2, 
                                                                                           refLine3,
                                                                                           refSurf, 
                                                                                           iOri1,
                                                                                           iOri2, 
                                                                                           iOri3);
        iHB.AppendHybridShape(HSCTT);
        iPart.InWorkObject = HSCTT;
        iPart.Update();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return HSCTT;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did try that and it didn't work. It seemed to me that the problem was with the user privileges. For some reason, I cannot access some of the properties if I am not the admin. I don't understand why...